# Show values of one2many in tree

Tags: odoo

I have a tree table inside of another tree table. When I'm editing, the nested table is properly shown inside of the cell. But when I just view the values, there are just comma separated ids in the cell (instead of the nested table). How can I display the table in the cell or at least formatted values in the view mode?

Nested table:

```
<record id="view_mrp_repair_line_item_tree" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">mrp.repair.line.item.tree</field>
    <field name="model">mrp.repair.line.item</field>
    <field name="type">tree</field>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <tree string="Repair line items" editable="bottom">
            <field name="description" />
            <field name="price" />
        </tree>
    </field>
</record>
```

The parent table:

```
<field colspan="4" mode="tree" name="operations" nolabel="1" widget="one2many_list">
    <tree string="Operations" editable="bottom">
        ...
        <field name="items" context="{'default_repair_line_id':active_id}" widget="one2many_list" />
    </tree>
</field>
```

Model from nested table:

```
class mrp_repair_line_item(osv.osv):
    _name = 'mrp.repair.line.item'

    _columns = {
        'repair_line_id': fields.many2one('mrp.repair.line', 'Repair Line', required=True),
        'description': fields.char('Description', required=False, size=160),
        'price': fields.float('Price', required=False)
    }

mrp_repair_line_item()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a functional field that returns a single string that represents the values and display that field instead. For example: `[description1: Price1], [description2: Price2], ...`

Comment: Thank you for response. I forgot to tell (but it is obvious from the code samples) that I use editing in row (`editable="bottom"`). So if I'm not mistaken I can't define two different views for edit mode and view mode. When I create the functional field as you told me, it'll be visible in both edit and view mode and it's not editable. Am I right? Is it normal that ids are displayed instead of the table?

Comment: You can define a function `fnct_inv` that implements the write operation for the functional field by parsing the string and modifying the one2many objects. That way, the field would be editable. To simplify editing and parsing, you can use a dictionary-like format: `description1: Price1, description2: Price2, ...`